# Output custom server log to console for next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

This is my custom server code on next.js, how will I be able to output the console.log to terminal when I run `next dev` or `next build` -> `next start`?

```
import express from 'express';
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';
import next from 'next';

import helmet from 'helmet';

const app = next({ dev: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

    server.use(helmet());
    server.use('/api', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/files', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/images', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/.well-known', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));

    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(80, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('> Ready on port 80');
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't `console.log('> Ready on port 80');` showing the output on the terminal where you started the server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a custom logger - You can use something like [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) - This implementation [link](https://medium.com/@svyandun/json-logging-with-express-and-bunyan-30af1c41c1e) provides detailed examples but the simplest logging would be

```
import express from 'express';
import bunyan from 'bunyan';
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';
import next from 'next';

import helmet from 'helmet';


const log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: "my-app",
  serializers: bunyan.stdSerializers,
});

const app = next({ dev: false });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;

    server.use(helmet());
    server.use('/api', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/files', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/images', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));
    server.use('/.well-known', proxy(API_URL, {
        proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
        limit: '50mb'
    }));


    server.all('*', (req, res) => {

// Bunyan logging request and finish 
req.log.info({ req });
  res.on("finish", () => req.log.info({ res }));


        return handle(req, res);

    });
    server.listen(80, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('> Ready on port 80');
    });
});
```